# Creating a URL with a FK

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to create a url which reads www.localhost/forum/{slug}/thread={id} but im encountering problems. The {id} part is coming back as that is the thread id but the {slug} part i'm trying to retrieve through a foriegn key and get the issue.

```
Call to a member function forums() on null
```

here are my tables 
**Forum**: id, name, slug, timestamps
**Thread**: id, name, forum_id, user_id

here is my relation on my thread model

```
public function forums(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum');
}
```

and here is my code on my ThreadController

```
    public function show($id, $slug)
{
    //
    $thread = Thread::find($id);
    $thread->forums()->slug = $slug;

    return view('forum.thread')->withThread($thread);
}
```

Any ideas on how i get the Forum's slug into the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Because  `$thread = Thread::find($id)` Didnt get any thread. You can can use `findOrFiail` function, or check does thread exist, and after that call `forums()`.

Comment: if it exist why you get this error? Call to a member function forums() on null ?? Can you add var_dump($thread);diel; before forum call, and show result?

Comment: the problem lies with the slug i think their is an error in the code as if i remove that code and change the url to localhost/forum/thread/thread=1 it works fine. the issue seems to be getting the slug from the FK into the url

Comment: Is ```slug``` an actual attribute or just something you are forcing in?

Comment: slug is a column of the forum table i am trying to achieve localhost/forum/{forum.slug}/thread={thread.id} at the moment i can only achieve localhost/forum/-/thread={thread.id}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `$thread->forums()->setAttribute('slug', $slug)`

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like `id` is not a route parameter.

your controller method should be

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $thread = Thread::find(request()->input('id'));
    $thread->forums()->slug = $slug;

   return view('forum.thread')->withThread($thread);
}
```

either that or change your route

Comment: Find(id) finds the id of the thread im showing and it does add it to the url correctly, thread={id} the issue is on the slug which is the forum for instance a coding forum so the route should show localhost/forum/coding/thread=1. but im having problem getting the coding slug to show in there

Comment: I would personally change the route to be `/forum/{slug}/{thread_id} `

Comment: what would be the controller code to get that to work>?

Comment: `public function show($slug, $thread_id)
{
    $thread = Thread::find($thread_id);
    $thread->forums()->slug = $slug;

   return view('forum.thread')->withThread($thread);
}`